# how to make SharePoint organizational structure from custom database instead of AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, organization-profile

I there a way to use a custom database with users and department instead of Active Directory?

can I sync users in user profile service with that custom database design instead of syncing it with other Active Directory?
and what you recommend me to use?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to use a custom database with users and department instead of Active Directory?**

**No,** you can't use a custom database instead of AD!

---

**Can I sync users in user profile service with that custom database design instead of syncing it with other Active Directory?**

You can configure `SharePoint user profile synchronization` to **only** pull and append Information from an external database using `Bussiness connectivity service` to **existing** objects!  Please Check the below **Trevor** clarification!

**Check the details steps** at [User Profile Imports using BCS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/user-profile-imports-using-bcs/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85633/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-how-to-make-sharepoint-organizatio).

Comment: after syncing will it make the organizational structure for the company ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something else other than Active Directory to create User Profiles, however you will need to develop the code yourself. I have an example using [AD LDS](https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePoint-LDAP-FBA/blob/master/Nauplius.ADLDS.UserProfiles/Nauplius.ADLDS.UserProfiles/Program.cs). The general methods should apply to your scenario, although you will need to construct your SQL queries, etc.

If your users are not authenticating with the same data source as you're using for your User Profiles, they will not be 'attached' to those imported profiles.

Comment: will this example show the organizational structure for the company based on the hierarchy you designed on the database ?